# spring mvc one init binder for all controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have 5 controllers and i would like to register an `InitBinder` to all of them.

I know i can add this code to each of them.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)
{
    binder.registerCustomEditor(StringWrapper.class, new StringWrapperEditor());
}
```

**But** i would like to define it only **once** (even create a bean of `StringWrapperEditor` and use it instead of creating new every time.)

I searched SO and some other places but didn't find any answear.
Is it even possible?

Im using spring 3.1.1 with java 1.6.

Comment: With Spring 3.2+, you should be able to define it in a `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class.

Comment: im using spring 3.1.1 - will edit the question

Comment: See [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/84541-application-wide-initbinder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a `PropertyEditorRegistrar` which registers all your custom `PropertyEditors`. Then in your configuration add a `ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer` which you hookup with the created `PropertyEditorRegistrar` and hook it to your `HandlerAdapter`.

```
public class MyPropertyEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {

    public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {
         registry.registerCustomEditor(StringWrapper.class, new StringWrapperEditor());   
    }
}
```

If you have a `<mvc:annotation-driven />` tag in your configuration, the problem is that with this tag you cannot add the `WebBindingInitializer` to the adapter next to that there is already a `ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer` added to the pre-configured HandlerAdapter. You can use a `BeanPostProcessor` to proces and configure the bean.

```
public class MyPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof RequestMappingHandlerAdapter) {
            WebBindingInitializer wbi = ((RequestMappingHandlerAdapter) bean).getWebBindingInitializer();
            if (wbi == null) {
                wbi = new ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer();
                ((RequestMappingHandlerAdapter) bean).setWebBindingInitializer(wbi);
            }

            if (wbi instanceof ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer) {
                ((ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer) wbi).setPropertyEditorRegistrar(new MyPropertyEditorRegistrar());
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Requires a bit of work but it is doable. You could also implement your own `WebBindingInitializer`.

If you don't have the tag you can simply manually configure a `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` and wire everything together.

Links

1. PropertyEditorRegistrar [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/PropertyEditorRegistrar.html)
2. ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer.html)
3. Reference Guide [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config)

Comment: Do you know if the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` generates bean definitions before or after your own `<bean>` declarations? If it was before, could you not find out what bean name it uses for its `WebBindingInitializer` and declare a `<bean>` that overwrites it?

Comment: i hoped it will be easier :)  ill give it a try!

Comment: You could try, as @SotiriosDelimanolis suggest, to detect the `ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer` instead of the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` that would save you a couple of lines. Although I'm not sure if the `ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer` is actually added as a bean to the context.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works! do you know why the function `registerCustomEditors` is been called every time?

Answer (score 3):

Though the initial question was about Spring 3.1, the following might be useful for those who use newer Spring versions.

One possible option is to move your @InitBinder to @ControllerAdvice, for example

```
@ControllerAdvice
class InitBinderControllerAdvice {
    @InitBinder
    fun initBinder(dataBinder: WebDataBinder) {
        dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(
            MLQueryOutputFormat::class.java,
            StringToMLQueryOutputFormat()
        )
        dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(
            IDatabaseOps.SortDirection::class.java,
            StringToSortDirection()
        )
    }
}
```

Regarding **ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer**, even though it's quite a powerful thing, it requires additional configuration in terms of validation and etc. **So pay attention to detail once implementing it**. For instance, the following code does the job as per InitBinder, but lacks setting a Validator. As a result, the validation of the rest controller param annotated with @Validated didn't work:

```
@Configuration
class WebMvcConfig {
    @Bean
    fun configurableWebBindingInitializer(): ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer {
        val initializer = ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer()
        initializer.propertyEditorRegistrars = arrayOf(
            PropertyEditorRegistrar {
                it.registerCustomEditor(
                    MLQueryOutputFormat::class.java,
                    StringToMLQueryOutputFormat()
                )
            }, PropertyEditorRegistrar {
                it.registerCustomEditor(
                    IDatabaseOps.SortDirection::class.java,
                    StringToSortDirection()
                )
            }
        )
        return initializer
    }
}
```

To add validation, one could do the following:

```
@Bean
fun configurableWebBindingInitializer(
    @Qualifier("defaultValidator") validator: Validator
): ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer {
    val initializer = ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer()
    initializer.validator = validator
    ...
```