# spring mvc how to improve my initBinder

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-mvc-initbinders

I am using spring mvc and am still trying to get my head around binders, formatters and converters.

I have a custom binder behind one of my controllers...

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    df.setLenient(false);
    webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(df, true));
}
```

This particular custom binder is not specific to just the form for this controller but will be used everywhere throughout the application.

What is the best way for me to do this more generically for all of my controllers?

P.S. I have got a conversion service so I could use this if it is the right place to do it.

```
public class ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean extends FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider the use of `@ControllerAdvice` annotation. The classes with this annotation assist every controller.

So you can write something like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalInitializer {

    @InitBinder
    public void globalBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
       SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
       df.setLenient(false);
       webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(df, true));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I am using spring mvc 3.1.0. I understand controller advice is only as of spring mvc 3.2. Is there anything similar in 3.1.0 I can use?

Comment: @Richie Hi! Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165135/spring-mvc-one-init-binder-for-all-controllers